# Can I reuse variables defined in Powershell validation blocks?

Tags: powershell, validation, global-variables

I've made a powershell script which validates some parameters. In the process of validation I need to create some strings. I also need these strings later in the script.

To avoid rebuilding the same strings again, can I reuse variables defined within validation blocks? Perhaps I can use functions in validation blocks somehow? Or maybe global variables? I'm not sure what's possible here, or what's good practice.

Example:

`Test.ps1`

```
Function Test {
    param(
        [string]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $thing1

        [string]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $thing2

        [string]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({
            $a = Get-A $thing1
            $b = Get-B $thing2
            $c = $a + $b
            $d = Get-D $c
            if(-not($d -contains $_)) {
                throw "$_ is not a valid value for the thing3 parameter."
            }
            return $true
        })]
        $thing3
    )

    # Here I'd like to use $c
    # At worst, calling Get-A and Get-B again may be expensive
    # Or it could just be annoying duplication of code
}
```

Bonus question, if this is possible, could I reuse those variables in a subsequent validation block?

Comment: For the first part you could try setting it as `$script:c` to make it a script-scope variable, and then it won't fall out of scope and get cleared up when the scriptblock finishes. (I don't know if you can depend on the order the validation blocks are executed for the bonus part)

Comment: I will be trying out using script-scope variables. FWIW, I'm already depending on the execution order of the validation by using $thing1 and $thing2 in the validation of `$thing3`. I still have yet to find official documentation of the execution order, but I've relied on it in the past, and have seen several SO questions that successfully did the same. That being said, I should probably be specifying my parameters as positional, to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a byref varliable.

This will affect the variable being passed to it so you could both have a return value and a parameter affected by the execution of your function.

[About Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6)

> You can pass variables to functions by reference or by value.
>
> When you pass a variable by value, you are passing a copy of the data.
>
> In the following example, the function changes the value of the
>   variable passed to it. In PowerShell, integers are value types so they
>   are passed by value. Therefore, the value of $var is unchanged outside
>   the scope of the function.

```
Function Test{
Param($thing1,$thing2,[ref]$c) 

$c.Value = new-guid

return $true

}

#$ThisIsC = $null 
test -c ([ref] $ThisIsC)

Write-Host $ThisIsC  -ForegroundColor Green
```

Alternatively, you can use the `$script` or the `$global` scope.

For a simple script to quickly expose your variable, the `$script`scope will do just that. A byref parameter might be easier for the end-user if you intend to distribute your function by making it clear you need to pass a reference parameter.

See [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6) documentation.

> Scopes in PowerShell have both names and numbers. The named scopes
>   specify an absolute scope. The numbers are relative and reflect the
>   relationship between scopes.
>
> **Global:** The scope that is in effect when PowerShell starts. Variables
>   and functions that are present when PowerShell starts have been
>   created in the global scope, such as automatic variables and
>   preference variables. The variables, aliases, and functions in your
>   PowerShell profiles are also created in the global scope.
>
> **Local:** The current scope. The local scope can be the global scope or
>   any other scope.
>
> **Script:** The scope that is created while a script file runs. Only the
>   commands in the script run in the script scope. To the commands in a
>   script, the script scope is the local scope.
>
> **Private:** Items in private scope cannot be seen outside of the current
>   scope. You can use private scope to create a private version of an
>   item with the same name in another scope.
>
> **Numbered Scopes:** You can refer to scopes by name or by a number that
>   describes the relative position of one scope to another. Scope 0
>   represents the current, or local, scope. Scope 1 indicates the
>   immediate parent scope. Scope 2 indicates the parent of the parent
>   scope, and so on. Numbered scopes are useful if you have created many
>   recursive scopes.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed you. Might be my fault for not specifying that this function is the entire script (so, a module I guess). Therefore I can't pass `$c`, or `[ref]$c` to the function. `$thing1`, `$thing2`, and `$thing3` are supplied by the end user. when running the script. I will give script-scope variables a shot though.

Comment: Script scope variable definitely work for this purpose, and I guess they make sense since I would otherwise be creating them in the script scope anyway. Just too bad that it has to be this ugly. TBH I might abandon the `ValidateScript` syntax and use old fashioned validation in the script itself. It's a nice concept, for simpler validation, but really makes clunky code for complex validation. Not to mention, it seems Powershell fails to report accurate line numbers when there's errors. Runtime errors in validation blocks appear to always be reported at `Line 1, Character 1`. Anyway, thanks.